# Search for records with same value in one column but varying values in a another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, count, distinct

Apologies for my very ambiguous title, but i've been working on this for the better part of a day and can't get anywhere so i'm probably clouded.. Let me present sample data and explain what I'm trying to do:

```
+------+------+
| ID   | UW   |
+------+------+
| 1    | I    |
| 1    | I    |
| 3    | I    |
| 3    | I    |
| 3    | C    |
| 3    | C    |
| 4    | C    |
| 4    | C    |
```

I'm trying to find the count of IDs where there are both "I" and "C" in the UW column, so in the example above the count would be: 1 (for ID #3). Since ID 1 has only "I" and ID 4 has only "C" values in "UW" field. Thanks in advance for helping me with this, much appreciated.

Comment: Since you've been working on it, can you post your latest effort and in what way it didn't work?   Did you get an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.ID) N
FROM dbo.YourTable A
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTable
             WHERE ID = A.ID
             AND UW IN ('I','C'));
```

And another:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (  SELECT ID
        FROM dbo.YourTable 
        WHERE UW IN ('I','C')
        GROUP BY ID
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT UW) = 2) A;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `having` to get the ids that meet the conditions:

```
select id
from table t
group by id
having sum(case when uw = 'I' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when uw = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

You can then count these with a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select id
      from table t
      group by id
      having sum(case when uw = 'I' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when uw = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
     ) t
```

I like to formulate these problems this way, because the `having` clause is very general on the types of conditions that it can support.

Comment: that's a really interesting method Gordon, and really easy to understand. Never had someone show me something like this, so thanks! I'll add this to my own documents to reference later :)